# Left join on column that has the highest value

Tags: r, conditional-statements, left-join

I am facing a problem where I want to join two data frames based on two columns. However, I only want to join based on the column that has the highest value. If the values are equal to each other, I do not care on which column we join.

**EDITED Example (with date column)**

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2020-09-01"), by = "day", length.out = 5), A = c(0, 0, 1, 5, 0), B = c(1, 0, 2, 3, 0))
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), B = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), C = c(.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5))
```

```
df1            | df2 
date       A B | A B C
2020-09-01 1 0 | 0 0 .5
2020-09-02 0 0 | 1 1 1
2020-09-03 1 2 | 2 2 1.5
2020-09-04 5 3 | 3 3 2 
2020-09-05 0 0 | 4 4 2.5
               | 5 5 3 
               | 6 6 3.5
```

I want to produce a left join with `df1` as the `LHS`, and `df2` as the `RHS`. It needs to give the following result for `df_final`:

```
df_final
date       A B C
2020-09-01 0 1 1 
2020-09-02 0 0 .5
2020-09-03 1 2 1.5
2020-09-04 5 3 3
2020-09-05 0 0 .5
```

So, basically: if A > B, join on A; if A < B, join on B; if A == B, join on A (can also join on B, output is the same).

Comment: I don't get it. What is the difference in choosing the column make when df2$A and df2$B are identical (both are 0:6)?

Comment: Yes that's right, but in `df1` the values are different. You can see `df2$A` and `df2$B` as identical, but the `left_join` is  dependent on `df1$A` and `df1$B` and I want to join on whatever value is higher in `df1`. Does this make sense? Else I can try to be more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  #Create a row number column
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  #Get data in long format
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B)) %>%
  #join df2 in long format
  left_join(df2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B)), by = c('name', 'value')) %>%
  #For each row
  group_by(row) %>%
  #select C value corresponding to max value
  mutate(C = C[which.max(value)]) %>%
  #get data in wide format
  pivot_wider() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  #select relevant columns
  select(A, B, C)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#      A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     1   1  
#2     0     0   0.5
#3     1     2   1.5
#4     5     3   3  
#5     0     0   0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, Ronak. The solution works for this example, but the data I work with is a bit more complicated. `df1` and `df2` are larger and contain more variable types, which makes the `pivot_longer` throw an error. I will edit my example to reflect this.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Cannot combine values of different types? If you have other columns you need to get only column `A` and `B` in long format. See updated `cols` argument in `pivot_longer`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` and `B` are redundant in `df2` (at least in your example), it might be sufficient to select `C` according to the matching row of the `max` value of `df1`.

```
res <- transform(df1, C=df2$C[match(apply(df1[-1], 1, max), df2$A)])
res
#         date A B   C
# 1 2020-09-01 0 1 1.0
# 2 2020-09-02 0 0 0.5
# 3 2020-09-03 1 2 1.5
# 4 2020-09-04 5 3 3.0
# 5 2020-09-05 0 0 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it works for this example and also for my data. But, I was also looking for a "clean" way to do it in dplyr (for example). But thank you nevertheless, I have my problem solved :)